# Upsert SQL query throwing error with golang and squirrel. SQL error at or near where

Tags: sql, go, squirrel-sql

`sql err: 'pq: syntax error at or near "WHERE"', sql: 'INSERT INTO table (id,user,type) VALUES ($1,$2,$3) ON CONFLICT WHERE id = $4 AND user = $5 DO UPDATE SET type = $6', params: [3 158 up 3 158 up]`

Using the info on [this](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/) page, I thought I could chain together an `INSERT` statement with an `ON CONFLICT` clause such that if `user` and `id` were found in the same row of the table, update that row instead.  Where is the syntax error mentioned above?

Comment: A lone `WHERE` clause as the *`conflict_target`* is NOT allowed. The *`conflict_target`*, when not using the `ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name` variant, MUST consist of one or more *`index_column_name`* columns and/or *`index_expression`* expressions, and an optional *`index_predicate`*.

Comment: Show the table definition including all its indexes/constraints so we can see and suggest what would be a valid candidate for the *`conflict_target`*.